# Subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<User>' Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

From angular 4 to angular 6 code now i am getting error in vs code saying property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise' . The error is in the Profile.component.ts . Not sure what the problem is

Below is the code

**User Class**

```
export class User {
   id: number
   name: string
   email: string
   avatar: string
   joined: string
}
```

**User Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { AuthService } from './auth.service'
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { CONFIG } from '../config/config'
import { User } from '../classes/User'
import 'rxjs'


    @Injectable()

    export class UserService {
        private headers: Headers
        constructor(private authService: AuthService, private http: Http) {
            this.headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}` })
        }

        getUserById(id: number): Promise<User> {
            if (id == this.authService.getAuthUserId()) {
                return Promise.resolve(this.authService.getAuthUser())
            }

            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers })
            this.http.get(`${CONFIG.API_URL}/user/${id}`, options)
                .subscribe((response) => {
                    console.log(response.json())
                })
        }
    }
```

**Profile Component .ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service'
import { User } from '../classes/User'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number
  user: User
  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((param) => {
      this.id = +param['id']
    })

    this.userService.getUserById(this.id)
      .subscribe((user) => this.user = user)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message self explanatory. You are trying to access `subscribe` function of `Promise` which is not available.

You should use `then` instead of `subscribe`

```
  this.userService.getUserById(this.id)
      .then((user) => this.user = user)
  }
```

Note: You may need to change the implementation of `getUserById` as well. Since it looks incorrect.

```
getUserById(id: number): Promise<any> {
            const p = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) =>  {
            if (id == this.authService.getAuthUserId()) {
                return resolve(this.authService.getAuthUser())
            }
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers })
            this.http.get(`${CONFIG.API_URL}/user/${id}`, options)
                .subscribe((response) => {
                    resolve(response.json())
                })

      });
      return p;

  }
```

> Note : Since the code was written in the stackoverflow editor directly. There could be typo or syntactical error. Please correct yourself.

Comment: If a change it to "then" , it says nothing but shows an error in console .
By consoling TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Profile.component.ts .

Comment: Check the answer with changes in `getUserById` function.

Comment: Below occurs at "return p"
Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<User>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'User'.

Comment: Change `Promise<User>`  to `Promise<any>`.

Comment: Thank you Sir . It Worked :-) can you explain me what was the exact error ?